# How to know when there is a repeated data?

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, vb.net

I have a database on SQL Server with a primary key and two other columns, one with the date and the other with the time.

The date column can repeat its values several times but the time one won't.

I need my Visual Studio Windows Forms application to read the database and tell me when there is a `Date` value repeated and then let me choose between multiple `Times`. How do I do that?

For the combobox fillers I use this code, is the same for both

```vb
Public Sub FillCombo(ByVal ComboBox As ComboBox, ByVal sql As String)
    conectarbase()
    Try
        nConexion.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, nConexion)

        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

        Dim ds As New DataSet 
        da.Fill(ds) 
        ComboBox.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        ComboBox.DisplayMember = ds.Tables(0).Columns(0).Caption.ToString

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString, "ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        If nConexion.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            nConexion.Close()
        End If
    End Try
End Sub
```

Is showing me this error:

> Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString' property. The connection's current state is open.

At the GUI I use, for the first combo:

```vb
FillCombo(ComboBox1, "SELECT dateCol From MyTable where User='" + TextBox.Text + "' Group By dateCol ")
```

for the second one:

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    FillCombo(ComboBox2, "SELECT TimeCol from MyTable where DateCol='" + ComboBox1.SelectedText + "'")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an application with 2 list boxes (or gridviews). The first list box would be populated from aquery like this:

```
SELECT dateCol, Count(*) From myTable Group By dateCol Having Count(*)>1
```

This will show you rows with 2 or more repeated dates and their number in the database.

Click on any of those dates to populate the 2nd listbox with a query like

```
SELECT key, dateCol, TimeCol where dateCol = SelectedDateFromListbox1
```

Each row in the 2nd list box will show full record information.

There are different scenarios for the GUI of course.

Comment: What If there is another field(user) also repeated several times with an assigned date and a time.

in the gui the user estipulates  the user. so i want the list box 1 to show all the dates of that user, and after that the times.

Comment: If the user value is input (say from a textbox), the first query could be qualified by the user value as: SELECT dateCol, Count(*) From myTable WHERE (user=TextBoxUserValue) Group By dateCol Having Count(*)>1

Comment: it keeps showing me the message, i treid to just use 1 combobox filler but it didnt work

Comment: It is not obvious why you are getting the error. I suggest you remove the line "nConexion.Open()" and try. If you still get the same error, may be start a new question with full code.

Comment: thanks i solve it, it was a problem with the order i called the procedures

Comment: your answer was really useful

Answer (score 2):

```
select date, time, count(*)
from table
group by date, time
```

count should always be 1 (if time is unique), but you never know....

Comment: If you want only the ones that are "bad" add a `having count(*) > 1` on the end.

Comment: You should use group by structure with those fields.